# CakePHP: Hide the /index action using Routing

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-2.2

What is the correct way to hide the `/index` action while having url parameters using Routing in CakePHP apps and the Html-Helper?

I want to be able to show urls like `/books/2` while using the HTML helper

```
echo $this->Html->link('Books', array(
    'controller'=>'books', 'action'=>'index', 2
));
```

Tried the following in my `routes.php`

```
Router::connect('/books/:id', array('controller' => 'books'), array(
    'id' => '[0-9]+',
    'pass' => array('id')
));
```

Output is: `http://www.example.com/books/index/2`

Wanted is: `http://www.example.com/books/2`

Comment: have you tried adding 'action' => 'index' in the array?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I tried this - just forgot to mention it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use the `id` key in the routing array when creating links:

```
echo $this->Html->link('Books', array(
    'controller'=>'books', 'action'=>'index', 'id' => 2
));
```

Comment: It had to be so easy... did it? :) Thank you sir!

Comment: Got an old code and this is a good solution. In general, you need to match all parameters in the router connect and the generator will give you the right output. Thanks.